# not allowed to load local resource in Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, directory

Google Chrome won't allow me to open a local directory with a button. I tried
the same thing with IE and it works perfectly, is there a workaround for this?

when I look at the dev tooks console, it prints:
    **Not allowed to load local resource:**

here's the simple html that I'm using:

```
<form action="file://///directory/test/CB/">
                        <input type="submit" value="open folder" />
                    </form>
```

Comment: check console log you can't do this in edge either

Comment: is there a workaround for that? **Not allowed to load local resource** is what I get when I check the console log

Comment: think about what you are asking.  do you really want a web page to be able to access your local c drive?  This would let anyone take over your machine if you visited their web page. so no, there is no work around

Comment: I'm not willing to access a local C drive, it's a shared folder over the network

Comment: yeah, that's a lot better.  you can compromise everyone's machine